# Can I drag a window into a new tab of another window

Tags: finder, tabs

I have two Finder windows open. Window A has a single tab (or no tabs) while Window B has multiple. Now I want to drag Window A to join the tabs in the Window B. Is there any way to do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a shortcut you can use.  In Finder you can select menu item Window / Merge All Windows

[image]

Comment: That serves the purpose!